# 404 Attribute Routing in Area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

I am receiving an IIS 404 error message when I try to go to the index method in my home controller in the `agency` area.  If I update the `route` attribute to: `[Route("{action}")]` it works fine, but I want to keep `index` as the default route.

In my view I have this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click here", "index", "home", new { area = "agency" }, new { @class = "btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" })
```

HomeController in Agency Area

```
namespace ProjectName.UI.Areas.Agency.Controllers
{
    [RouteArea("agency")]
    [RoutePrefix("home")]
    [Route("{action=index}")]
    public class HomeController : BaseController
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

RouteConfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] { "ProjectName.UI.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

I also have an Admin Area that looks exactly the same as the Agency area, except the `RouteArea` is `admin` and I don't have any problems.

Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was because my area was called `Agency` and in my `Views` folder I had another subfolder called `Agency`.  Instead of routing to `agency/home/index` it was trying to find a `home` view inside my `agency` folder.